# How to write Swift Protocol methods in Objective C

Tags: objective-c, swift, class, delegates, protocols

I have a file Slider.swift  and there is protocol defined with Class Parameter. i want to write that methods in Objective C in header file. how to Pass class as parameter in Protocols.

Please help

```
public protocol SliderDelegate: class {
    func slider(slider: Slider, textWithValue value: Double) -> String

    func sliderDidTap(slider: Slider)
    func slider(slider: Slider, didChangeValue value: Double)
    func slider(slider: Slider, didUpdateFocusInContext context: UIFocusUpdateContext, withAnimationCoordinator coordinator: UIFocusAnimationCoordinator) }

public extension SliderDelegate {
    func slider(slider: Slider, textWithValue value: Double) -> String { return "\(Int(value))" }

    func sliderDidTap(slider: Slider) {}
    func slider(slider: Slider, didChangeValue value: Double) {}
    func slider(slider: Slider, didUpdateFocusInContext context: UIFocusUpdateContext, withAnimationCoordinator coordinator: UIFocusAnimationCoordinator) {} }

@IBDesignable public class Slider: UIView {

}
```

Comment: You're going to have to be more clear what exactly you're trying to achieve.

Comment: try adding `@objc` to the beginning of the protocol declaration. that should expose it to Objective-C when importing the Swift module